# is there a tool that can extract all strings from any type of file?

Tags: linux, string, passwords, extract

i'm looking for an alternative to [wyd 0.2](http://www.remote-exploit.org/?page_id=418) that can extract strings from any type of file it comes across.

thanks =)

Comment: Why do you need it and why is `wyd` unsuitable for you? If you provide this information, people can help you better.

Comment: wyd removes certain characters like ":" which i'd like to keep. i have tried editing the code but no luck from doing so.

Comment: oh wow nvm. i didn't realize strings was built into linux already :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strings`

/*padding because i need 15 chars*/

**edit** There is a program called `strings` in every *nix out there, since the late '80s, which does just that. You can log in to any *nix out there, and type `man strings` to get more info. Or you could type `strings -h` showing something along the lines of

```
Usage: strings [option(s)] [file(s)]
Display printable strings in [file(s)] (stdin by default)
The options are:
-a - --all                Scan the entire file, not just the data section
-f --print-file-name      Print the name of the file before each string
-n --bytes=[number]       Locate & print any NUL-terminated sequence of at
-<number>                 least [number] characters (default 4).
-t --radix={o,d,x}        Print the location of the string in base 8, 10 or 16
-o                        An alias for --radix=o
-T --target=<BFDNAME>     Specify the binary file format
-e --encoding={s,S,b,l,B,L} Select character size and endianness:
                        s = 7-bit, S = 8-bit, {b,l} = 16-bit, {B,L} = 32-bit
@<file>                   Read options from <file>
-h --help                 Display this information
-v --version              Print the program's version number
```

which are then options you can pass to `strings`, to alter it's behavior.

Comment: There is a reason why 15 characters are required.

Comment: @zvonimir @MKv4: this should do it ;-)

Comment: ok if you need more info on how to use `strings`, just drop me a line.